# IIS sending different user page

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, caching, iis

I have a problem that appears while using concurrent users in IIS/.Net 3.5.

I am logged in using two users to the same server (user1, user2), both are using different computers. If I press on a link to one page using user1 and immediately on the same link to the same page using user2, I receive the sent page to user1 on both computers.
It seems that IIS is caching the requests and sending it to both computers even though that both are logged in using different accounts.

This never happens if you wait a bit before doing that. Is there any specific IIS configuration that caches those requests? How can I link it to per account instead to all? At worst case, how can I disable it?

Any tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, have a look at [ASP.NET output caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms228124(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Oh thank you. This solved it. Could you please put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET has a configurable/extensible output caching mechanism.

You can configure/disable the stock page output caching in web.config, or write your own custom output cache provider and refer to that in web.config.

There's information about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms228124(v=vs.100).aspx).